# Need to draw / animate a small square background image, then repeat it over x and y

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, svg

Basically, I would like to draw a small square, then draw another and then another until it fills the screen both horizontally and vertically.  I'd like to actually see the animation of each square being drawn.

I am not sure how to achieve this.  I know html canvas has a createPattern function but I think that uses an image and I need these squares to chain one after another (not all at once).

Any ideas?

A solution using jquery, canvas, svg, css3, html5 or maybe a popular svg or js library is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result you want?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var sq_size=10;
var sq_pos_x = 0-sq_size;//see comment in drawtick
var sq_pos_y = 0;
var can_width=800;
var can_height=600;
var tmr;
function startTimer(){
tmr = setInterval(function(){drawtick()}, 20);
}
function drawtick(){
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
//the first drawn square should not be on x+ sq_size
// instead of adding an extra if statement, I just initialized it on -sq_size
if(sq_pos_x+sq_size>=can_width)              {sq_pos_y=sq_pos_y+sq_size;sq_pos_x=0}else{sq_pos_x=sq_pos_x+sq_size;}
if(sq_pos_y>=can_height){clearInterval(tmr);alert('loop ended');}
ctx.rect(sq_pos_x,sq_pos_y,sq_size,sq_size);
ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTimer()">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

or

http://jsfiddle.net/kKyA5/

it all depense on the draw animation

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is actually pretty close, at least to the general idea of what I want.  My ultimate goal is to progressively draw a background like [THIS](http://i.imgur.com/uttzTqc.jpg).  I'd probably need to setup a few different color variables and randomly fill the squares.  I may be able to work from what you provided.

Comment: The first example is closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [oCanvas](http://ocanvas.org/), it's object oriented javascript, and it's based on the html5 canvas tag for drawing, it'll allow you to do some pretty neat stuff, and handle animation too. 
Basically you need to define the canvas tag with an id like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="354" height="100"></canvas>
```

and then instanciate the core object:

```
var canvas = oCanvas.create({
    canvas: "#canvas",
    background: "#0cc"
});
```

After that you could draw the squares with something like this:

```
var limit = 50;
var reduction = 2; //minus two pixels for iteration
var width = 202;
var height = 202;
for (var i = 1; i <= limit; ++i){

var rectangle = canvas.display.rectangle({
    x: 77,
    y: 77,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fill: "#0aa"
    });
width = width - reduction;
height = width - reduction;

canvas.addChild(rectangle,false);

}
```

and then draw it all at once:

```
canvas.draw.redraw();
```

Or you can [animate](http://ocanvas.org/docs/Animation/animate) it too

And it's well [documented](http://ocanvas.org/docs)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Wouldn't the code above just draw 50 squares on top of each other?  Also, what is the var reduction = 2; //minus two pixels for iteration line for?

Comment: @user3204142 it's just an example don't use it. This draws concentric squares, I thought that's what you needed.